# Passing a pointer to a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, pass-by-value

I was trying to implement BST using C++ , so i tried this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    struct node
    {
      int value;
      node* left;
      node* right;
    };

    void insert(node *cur , int val)
    {
      if(!cur)
      {
        cur = new node;
        cur->value = val;
        cur->left = NULL;
        cur->right = NULL;
        return;
      }

      if(val <= cur->value)
        insert(cur->left , val);
      else
        insert(cur->right , val);
    }

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      node *root = NULL;


      insert(root , 20);
      insert(root , 21);

      cout<<(*root).value;

      return 0;
    }
```

but I have a problem, my `insert()` function works good, but the change in `cur` does not seem to reflect into the `root` pointer, as `root` remains `NULL` after the `insert() function calls. What is wrong here?

EDIT: Thanks for all your answers, making a pointer to a pointer seems to be to be ugly and tedious, is there any other way around, acheiving this with some other design?

Comment: parameters are passed by value (the function receives a copy of the value of the parameter). So `cur` is a local copy of the calling parameter, that's why `cur = whatever` modifies the local parameter. You need to pass it by reference i.e. `node *&cur`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the `root` itself has been passed to `insert()` using pass-by-value. so, from `insert()`, the value of `root` cannot be changed. In other words, the `cur` is local to `insert()` function. Any changes made to `cur` itself won't impact the actual argument passed.

If you want to change the value of `root` from `insert()`, you need to pass a pointer to `root` from `main()`.

To elabotare, you can change the *value at the address* pointed by `cur` from `insert()`. So, following the same analogy, if you change

1. `insert(&root , 20);`
2. `void insert(node **cur , int val)`
3. all the occurrences of `cur` to `*cur`

you should be all good to go.

Comment: Would be nicer to use `void insert(node *& cur, int val)`, that would pass the pointer as reference...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the function to operate on the *outside* pointer rather than a *local copy* you need to pass by reference:

```
void insert(node*& cur, int val)
{
    // ... 
}
```

Otherwise the function works on a *copy* of the pointer and the *outside* variable remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The wrong is that you pas a pointer by value, change that value but the caller does not know about it. Change it to

```
void insert(node **cur , int val)
{
if(!*cur)
{
    *cur = new node;
    (*cur)->value = val;
    (*cur)->left = NULL;
    (*cur)->right = NULL;
    return;
}

if(val <= (*cur)->value)
    insert((*cur)->left , val);
else
    insert((*cur)->right , val);
}
```

And change function call accordingly (...exercise!)

Answer (score 0):

C++ makes function calls as Call by Value. So it makes a copy of the pointer and passes that to the function. If you pass that pointer, you have access to the data the pointer is pointing to, but NOT to the pointer outside the function itself, as only the adress the pointer is pointing to is copied.

You need to pass a pointer to the pointer if you want to modify the pointer itself (that would be the C attempt) or pass by reference, of which c++ is capable of.

If you want to use the C attempt:

```
void insert(node ** cur , int val)
if(!(*cur))
{
    (*cur) = new node;
    (*cur)->value = val;
    (*cur)->left = NULL;
    (*cur)->right = NULL;
    return;
}
```

or the C++ attempt (here you only have to modify the type of cur, everthing else will remain as it is):

```
void insert(node *& cur , int val)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you reassign cur to a new node in insert, that does not mean that root is assigned that value (especially that root is not an address at all, but NULL).

Either pass a pointer to an empty node to insert on initialization (and update it with relevant data) or return a new node (and assign it to root in main).