# Pointer's value not changing

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

```
class node{
    public:    node* next;
               int data;
};
void insert_node(node* head, int val){
    node* n = new node();
    n->next = NULL;
    n->data = val;
    cout << n->data << endl;
    if (head == NULL){   //point .1.
        head = n;        //point .2.
        cout<<"checkpoint 1 reached"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        node* p = head;
        while (p->next !=NULL)
            p= p->next ;
        p->next = n;
        head->next = n;
    }
    return ;
}
int main(){
    node* head = NULL;
    insert_node(head, 3);
    insert_node(head, 4);
    insert_node(head, 5);
    insert_node(head, 6);
    insert_node(head, 7);
    insert_node(head, 8);
    insert_node(head, 9);
    insert_node(head, 0);
}
`
```

In the above mentioned basic linked-list code , each time when i call insert_node function it reaches **point .1.** which means always head has/points to NULL, which indeed means that head is not being updated -but i'm updating it at **point .2.**. Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a pointer to a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413514/passing-a-pointer-to-a-function)

Answer (score 5):

A pointer is a variable like any other variable, so it can be passed either by value, by reference, or by pointer to it. You pass it *by value*,

```
void insert_node(node* head, int val)
```

If you want to change it, pass it by reference

```
void insert_node(node* & head, int val)
```

or by pointer to it

```
void insert_node(node** head, int val)
```

It's probably easiest to pass by reference, as it doesn't involve any code changing. You can also use a `typedef node* NODEPTR;` as a type alias, and then things become a bit more transparent,

```
void insert_node(NODEPTR head, int val) // a bit more clear that head is passed by value
```